# Не выводится пользователь в Windows 10

Tags: windows

Добавил нового пользователя через оснастку "Локальные пользователи и группы" и еще добавил новую группу. Назначил все права пользователя в групповой политике как у  администратора группе. В эту новую группу добавляю этого пользователя. Но пользователь не отображается при загрузке системы. Пробовал через реестр не получился. Пожалуйста помогите как исправить?

Comment: https://computer76.ru/2018/10/03/vse-polzovateli-windows-10/ или http://winitpro.ru/index.php/2017/06/14/otobrazhenie-vsex-polzovatelej-sistemy-na-ekrane-vxoda-windows-10/ Попробуйте

Comment: Пробовал не получилось. Windows выводит только те учетные записи, которые добавлены в стандартные группы Н-р: Администраторы, пользователи и т.д. А когда оставляю только мою группу, то перестает выводиться.